# How to do sort, calculation and find the maximum in python

Tags: python

recently I want to do some sorting, calculation and find the maximum in data frame.
For example:

```
data = {'Name':['Penny','Ben','Benny','Mark'], 
        'Eng':[5,1,4,3], 
        'Math':[1,5,3,2],
        'Physics':[2,5,3,1],
        'Sports':[4,5,2,3],
        'Total':[12,16,12,9]}
 
df1=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Eng','Math','Physics','Sports','Total']) 
df1
```

[image]

I want to get the range of different subject and I find a function

```
numpy.ptp
```

Which can find the range of values (maximum - minimum) along an axis,
thus I do this
import numpy as np

```
cols_of_interest = ['Eng','Math','Sports','Physics']
np.ptp(df1[cols_of_interest].values, axis=1)
```

Result

```
array([4, 4, 2, 2])
```

When I get the result, the information from the data frame is lost. For example, I want to find the students who have the largest range
should be (Penny:4, Ben:4)
However, when the data size is large, how can I merge those data back to the data frame and find the max?

Also, for `cols_of_interest = ['Eng','Math','Sports','Physics']`, when the elements are large (like 100 subjects), is there any elegant way to apply np.ptp?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply assign the output of `np.ptp`:

`df1['max_range'] = np.ptp(df1[cols_of_interest].values, axis=1)`

Finally, you can find the max with:
`max_val = df1['max_range'].max()` or `df1['max_range'].idxmax()` if you want the index of the max value.

> is there any elegant way to apply np.ptp?

You can access the columns of a dataframe with `df1.columns`. This returns a list of columns; then simply drop the names you do not want from that list, and pass it into `np.ptp`.

Comment: you can also use `df1[df1['max_range'].eq(df1['max_range'].max())]` to see only the rows from df1 where students have the largest range